# AWS VPC Subnetting

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, cidr

I have a VPC created with a CIDR block of 10.10.0.0/16.  I am trying to subnet that block into some /24's -- ie. 10.10.1.0/24

It wont let me.  The error I get is:
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR: 10.10.0.0/16.

My understanding is that I should be able to create subnets within the VPC CIDR block as long as they are smaller than the block.  I would expect /24 to fall within a /16.

Every subnet I've tried gives me the same error.  In reality, any subnetting of a block is going to have addreses overlapping within the block.

I'm at a loss here and could really use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem...

When building the VPC, where you specify the subnet CIDR, I had also made it 10.10.0.0/16.

Changing it to 10.10.0.0/24 allowed me to create the subnets I needed.